# Preserving dynamic textbox and value on postback

Tags: asp.net

Asking this as a narrower question as my last one was too broad.

Let's say I create a dynamic textbox using javascript - how do I make sure that on postback, this textbox is preserved ALONG WITH any value that the user has entered in it?

My js is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numMileage = 1;
    $('#addMileage').bind('click', function (event) {

        $('#page_content_containermileage').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" id="txtMileage' + numMileage + '" name="txtMileage' + numMileage + '" /></div></div>');
        numMileage += 1;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since HTTP is stateless protocol, you won't be able to get values after postback unless you do some handling.

If you intended to get those values in postback, then use `Request.Form["controlid"]` to get values in server side.

To persist the values on postback, you have to save them to `hidden field` ( set the values to hidden field , to what you get from postback) and on page load ( i meant `document.read()` or `window.load`)  reconstruct that using hidden field value. 
You will need JS to reconstruct that from hidden value.

Comment: Can I not use asp.net's Viewstate?  The js example above is adding one row with one textbox as an example - my users will potentially add a hundred or more textboxes to the form.

Comment: Since these are not `server controls` , you can not use `ViewState` because those values are never saved in viewstate. Info - ultimately viewstate stores encoded string in hidden field, i am suggest you to use hidden field. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx  - `ASP.NET server controls use this property`